# How can I store the value of an HTTP Post to my server?

Tags: python, server

I'm a complete newbie with web servers and such, and I'm trying to make a basic server to handle some simple raw text storage. I'm using Apache on Raspbian for the server, and using Python to handle the server (I know it's not really conventional).

My question is: How can I store the values of HTTP posts to the server? I know how to read and write to files, so I can use those for actually storing and reading the data, but I can't figure out how to read incoming HTTP posts.

I don't plan on using any other programming language, but I will be using some HTML. I also won't be using any sort of encryption. I just want to know how to handle HTTP Post requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle Post requests you need to run some kind of web service (a daemon, in other terms) that listen to the network for incoming requests. For this, you have several alternatives, but the easiest is to use a small/micro web framework that makes the daemon writing easy for you, such as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) (not selling this one in particular, but it's a micro framework quite easy to start with).

From their doc you have examples of how it may work:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['the_file']
        f.save('/var/www/uploads/uploaded_file.txt')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: But OP has already said he's using Apache. Are you suggesting this as an alternative to Apache or as an WSGI app inside Apache?

Comment: My suggestion would be to use it as a WSGI app inside Apache, yes. If there is a solution to handle the post that doesn't involve a web service I'm unaware of it.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.